# How to send contact from data direct to email without saving it on database, in WordPress Contact Forms?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api

I am currently using WordPress's API to integrate it with Vue.Js, and the request is that contact form which I am using should not save any data to WordPress CMS, it only need to submit it at email.

I am using: Contact Form 7 Plugin for WordPress!

Is there a possible way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could find, Contact Form 7 doesn't store submissions in the first place, see the screenshot down below.

Message displayed within the Contact Form 7 plugin:
[image]

However, if you want to stop plugins such as Flamingo from saving submissions on specific forms, you are able to give additional settings to your forms in Contact Form 7. To stop the messages from being stored you can add the setting `do_not_store: true`. More about additional settings [here](https://contactform7.com/additional-settings/#suppressing-message-storage).

Follow the following path to change the settings.

Contact -> Contact Forms -> edit -> Additional Settings

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem is that I needed to save on some form but not in others, so in this case your solution looks to work.